# Selector only working after inspecting/selecting element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have this code here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    debugger;
    $("div[id^='stage_']").click(function (e) { alert('Hello'); });
});
```

The weird thing I can't explain is, that when I execute the selector once I'm in the console when reaching the debugger statement, it returns an empty array, `[]`

But when I step out and go on the page, then hit Ctrl-Shift-C in Chrome to start inspecting and click on some of the div's that have the ID I'm looking for then execute the selector again in the console, now I have the elements I'm expecting.

I have even tried this here so to validate whether it was an async. loading issue (this is a system over which I don't have all the control). but still, when reaching the debugger, the selector doesn't work - even after waiting 10 seconds (which then I'm pretty sure the div's are there). I still have to go in inspector so jQuery recognize the elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //debugger;
    setTimeout(function() {
        debugger;
        $("div[id^='stage_']").click(function (e) { alert('allo'); });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Why would jQuery only be aware of elements that I've clicked on with Chrome's inspector ?

Comment: Is this/these element(s) added in the DOM following any async call (ajax e.g)?  If so, [delegate click event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to any static container

Comment: @A.Wolff Actually, this from a system that I don't have full control over. If that is the case, how can I tell jQuery to only execute my code when everything is loaded? I thought `.ready` would do the job.

Comment: No, jq ready pseudo event is when the DOM is ready, HTML parsed. It is different than window load event. So firstly try using as wrapper `$(window).on('load', function(){...});`. If still not working just delegate it using `$(document).on('click',"div[id^='stage_']", function(e){ alert('Hello'); });` (no needs of any event wrapper if event is delegated to document level). If delegation doesn't work, then something else stop your click event propagation. Other possibility would be to capture click event (jq doesn't support it) and filter the event target inside click handler

Comment: @A.Wolff I've added some details to my question

Comment: Well, are you sure this content isn't loaded inside an iframe?

Comment: Perhaps. So when I click those elements then execute the selector in the console, the code would be executed in the context of that iframe which is why they are found then ?

Comment: ya exactly. This would explain it. But it is really easy to check by inspecting rendered HTML from console. Or just execute in console after clicked specific DIV: `console.log('Inside iframe:', window.self !== window.top);`

Answer (score 33):

I know it's a bit late but when you open Dev Tools in Chrome the execution context is set to top. If your controls are located within an iFrame, that is a different context, not accessible from top. Use the dropdown to select your iFrame's context and your jQuery will return an element.

The reason it works when you inspect an element, is Chrome has selected the execution context for you already.

[image]

[Discussion about iFrame context in Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/get-started#javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Using the "on", it works even if the element exists after the page loads.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  //$("div[id^='stage_']").click( function (e) { alert('Hello'); });
  $("body").on('click','div[id^="stage_"]', function (e) { alert('Hello'); });
  $('body').html('<div id="stage_1">teste1</div>' +
                  '<div id="stage_2">teste2</div>' +
                  '<div>blabla</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

doc: http://api.jquery.com/on/